# What is the bar that shows which method my cursor is in called and where did it go when I upgraded to Android Studio 3.1.0

Tags: android-studio

There used to be this helpful bar at the top of my Android Studio Editor, below the file tabs, which showed which method the cursor was in. I'm finding that I'm desperately missing it since upgrading to Android Studio 3.1.0 from Android Studio 3.0.1. I couldn't figure out what it was called.

[image: picture of the missing bar]

It isn't a navigation bar, because that shows only the file path.

Answer (score 2):

After reloading the old version of Android Studio, I discovered that this bar is called **Breadcrumbs**.

The new version changes its appearance slightly and adds new options for whether to place it at the top or bottom of the editor window. It seems to default to being placed at the **bottom** of the editor window.

[image: Breadcrumbs Options]

To quickly set Breadcrumbs options <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (or macintosh equivalent) to bring up *Find Action* and search for *breadcrumbs*

[image: breadcrumbs search]

Hit enter on the non-options result and select *top* or whatever you want

[image: menu]

Enjoy having your breadcrumbs back on top.

[image]